# How to get the area surrounding the visible rect of the mapview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I can get the visible rect of a mapView with self.mapView.visibleMapRect, but how would I get a rect of the area which is slightly outside this rect?

```
---------------------
|                   |
|                   |
|    ----------     |     * the map shown on the screen 
|    |        |     |
|    |   *    |     |
|    |        |     |
|    ----------     |
|                   |
|                   | <- the rect that I want
---------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by 'the rect that I want'.  Are you talking about the parent view (or window)?  If it's a parent view and you're accessing it from the view controller, you can use **self.view.frame**.  You'd need to clarify what area it is that you're after.

Comment: i mean the coords, or rect, of a larger area of the map than is shown on the screen

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but the area of mapview outside of the viewable area is constantly shifting.  What is it you're trying to achieve - there may be another way of doing it.